# matplotlib swaps plotting of value 0 & 1 in cmap grays and cmap binary

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Noticed a strange behavior in matplotlib when plotting binary array (np.uint8) using cmap grayscale and also with binary

- CMAP = gray

Ideally `1` means `color white` and `0` means `color black`

Building an array of `np.ones` as below, and see the plot (strangely 1 is being plotted as "black")
[image]

Now changing some elements in the array to zero, and see the plot (now 1 is being plotted as white and 0 as black)?

[image]

**Question** : How is that the meaning on `1` changed when we have some zeros `0` in the array

- CMAP = binary

Ideally `0` means `color white` and `1` means `color black`

Building an array of `np.ones` as below, and see the plot (strangely 1 is being plotted as "white")

[image]

Now changing some elements in the array to zero, and see the plot (now 1 is being plotted as black and 0 as white)?

[image]

**Question** : How is that the meaning on `1` changed when we have some zeros `0` in the array

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance, as no one wants to retype data/code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Plots are okay.

Comment: `imshow` maps colors based on the values in the array, so of course the colors will change if the array changes. In this case, setting `vmin=0` will produce consistent results. Otherwise you need to map specific values to specific colors. The color order of `gray` and `binary` are opposite (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)